# Is it possible to generate PDF using dompdf from form data before submitting the form to database in laravel?

Tags: laravel, dompdf

Applogies for the question again. I'm new to laravel and this is my first project.
I'm trying to generate a pdf using DomPDF but before submitting my form to database, I dont know whether it is possible or not.

this is my create.blade.php code

```
@extends('layouts.main')
@section('content')

    <!-- Page Heading -->
    <div class="d-sm-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mb-4">
        <h1 class="h3 mb-0 text-gray-800">Orders</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-12">
                <div>
                    <div class="card-header">{{ __('Creating Order') }}
                        <a href="{{ route('orders.index') }}" class="float-right btn  btn btn-primary">Back</a>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <form method="GET" action="{{ route('orders.create') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            @csrf
                            <div class="form-row align-items-center">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-lg-5">
                                    <select id="customer_name" onchange="this.form.submit()" type="search" name="customer_id" class="form-control @error('customer_id') is-invalid @enderror" value="{{ old('customer_id') }}" required >
                                        <option selected></option>
                                        @foreach ($customers as $customer)
                                        <option value="{{ $customer->id }}">{{ $customer->customer_name }}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                    @error('customer_id')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-auto">
                                    <input id="btn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-3" value="Show Catalog" onclick="showDiv()">                                        
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="m-3">
                                Displaying Catalog for: <strong> <span style="color: red" id="customerName"></span><span style="color: red">. {{$count_linkeds}}</span></strong> items found in this Catalog.
                            </div>
                        </form>
                        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('orders.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">                            
                            @csrf
                            <main id="catalog" style="display: none" class="main">
                                <div class="container">
                                    <div class="row s6 m3">

                                        @foreach($linkeds as $lnkditem)

                                        <div class="col s6 m3">
                                            <div class="card item-images">
                                                <div class="img-wrapper">
                                                    <img src="{{ asset('uploads/linkedItems/'.$lnkditem->item_image) }}" width= '50' height='50' class="img img-responsive" />
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="card-content mt-2 item">
                                                    <h6 style="font-size: 18px">
                                                        Product Name: <strong style="color: red">{{ $lnkditem->product->product_name}}</strong>
                                                    </h6>
                                                    <div style="float: right; margin-top: -30px">
                                                        <label hidden style="float: right;" for="linked_id">{{ __(': Linked ID') }}</label>
                                                        <textarea hidden style="text-align: center; resize: none; width:100px; height: 28px; overflow:hidden; border:none; background-color: #f8f8f8;" readonly rows="1" name="linked_id" id="linked_id" class="form-control"
                                                        value="{{ old('linked_id', $lnkditem->id) }}">{{ $lnkditem->id}}</textarea>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <p>
                                                        Product description: <strong style="color: red"> {{ $lnkditem->product->product_description}}</strong>
                                                    </p>
                                                        Item Name: <span readonly id="item_name" name="item_name" style="font-weight: bold; color: black" value="{{ $lnkditem->item->item_name}}">{{ $lnkditem->item->item_name}}</span>
                                                    <p>
                                                        Item description: <strong style="color: black"> {{ $lnkditem->item->item_description}}</strong>
                                                    </p>
                                                    <p>
                                                        Supplier Ref.: <strong style="color: black"> {{ $lnkditem->supplier_ref_no}}</strong>
                                                    </p>
                                                    <p>
                                                        Supplier Barcode: <strong style="color: black"> {{ $lnkditem->supplier_barcode}}</strong>
                                                    </p>

                                                    <div class="pass-quantity col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-3 pl-0">
                                                        
                                                        <label for="item_quantity" class="pass-quantity">Quantity:</label>
                                                        <input style="color: red" name="item_quantity" class="form-control" type="number" value="0" min="0">
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div>
                                                        <label for="pass-quantity" class="pass-quantity" style="color: red; font-weight: bold; float: right; margin-right: 45px !important; margin-top: -32px">Item Price: AED - </label>
                                                        <p type="number" name="item_cost" class="item_cost" style="color: red; font-weight: bold; float: right; margin-top: -32px">
                                                            {{ $lnkditem->item_cost}}
                                                        </p>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="product-price d-none">{{ $lnkditem->item_cost}}</div>

                                                    <hr class="sidebar-divider">
                                                    <strong style="color: red"><p>Total Amount: AED:</p></strong>
                                                    <div class="product-line-price pt-4 pb-4 text-uppercase" style="color: red; font-weight: bold; float: right; margin-top: -67px">
                                                        <strong><span style="color: red" type="number" class="product-line-price">0.00</span></strong>
                                                    </div>

                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="card card-action mb-3 pt-4" style="padding: 15px; height: 100%; width: 50%; margin-left: 25%">
                                    <div class="mb-3" style="margin-left: 15px">
                                        <label for="order_unq_id"></label>
                                        Order UID: <textarea name="order_unq_id" style="color: red; font-weight: bold; width: 350px; resize: none; margin-left: 22%; margin-top: -31px !important; height: 38px; overflow:hidden; border:none; background-color: #f8f8f8;" readonly rows="1" id="order_unq_id" class="form-control @error('order_unq_id') is-invalid @enderror" value="{{ old('order_unq_id') }}">
                                        </textarea>
                                    </div>
                                    <div style="margin-left: 20px">
                                        Saving Order for - <strong> <span class="text-uppercase" style="color: red" id="order_save_customerName"></span></strong>
                                        
                                        <input type="text" class="customerName_order_save_input" hidden id="customerName_order_save_input" value="">
                                    </div><br>
                                    <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-4 col-md-5 totals">
                                        <div class="border border-gainsboro mb-3 px-3">
                                            <div class="border-bottom border-gainsboro">
                                                <p class="text-uppercase mb-0 py-3 bg-primary text-white text-center"><strong>Order Summary</strong></p>
                                            </div>
                                            <p class="mt-3 text-uppercase">Subtotal AED:</p>
                                            <div class="totals-item d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between"
                                            style="float: right; margin-top: -40px">
                                            <p class="totals-value" id="cart-subtotal"></p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="totals-item d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                                            <p class="text-uppercase">Aprox. VAT @5%</p>
                                            <p class="totals-value tax" id="cart-tax"></p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="totals-item totals-item-total d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mt-3 pt-3 border-top border-gainsboro">
                                            <label for="total" class="text-uppercase" style="color: red;"><strong>grand Total</strong></label>
                                            <input type="text" class="total_input" hidden id="total_input" name="total_input" value="0.00">
                                            <textarea style="self-align: center; text-align: right; color: red; padding-top !important; 10px; resize: none; width:100px; height: 35px; overflow:hidden; border:none; background-color: white; font-size: 18px" readonly rows="1"
                                              class="totals-value font-weight-bold cart-total" name="total" id="total" style="color: red;"></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <a type="submit" target="_blank" class="btn btn-success" href="{{route('mht_order_pdf')}}">Generate PDF</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="save_order" >Save Order</button>
                                </div>
                            </main>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

@endsection
```

I dont want pdf to get data from database. I need to generate the pdf with form data before form gets submit to database. Is this possible to achive? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of tecnicality, this is possible. Personally I've done something like this, only that the PDF is being generated after the form is stored to DB, but before the request is sent back to users.

So in the controller, you can do something like this:

```php
// first validate request inputs..

// then generate the PDF
PDF::generate('order_pdf');  // or something, idk what's the actual syntax

// finally 
return view('order_dashboard');
```

However you need to know that while the `PDF::generate()` line is being executed, the app will wait until it finished before moving to the next line, meaning that the execution is being done synchronously. Thus if the PDF generation takes too long, user will have to wait for it. To face this issue, you might want to look at [Laravel's Queue](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues) so that the PDF generation can be executed asynchronously.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @rifqy, tried your suggested code but no Success.

Comment: Please let me know if someone needs anymore details.

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried and explain how it failed